# Logic question (universal and existential quantifications)

Tags: math, computer-science, logic

I have a logical statement that says "If everyone plays the game, we will have fun".

In formal logic we can write this as:

Let D mean the people playing.
Let G be the predicate for play the game.
Let F be the predicate for having fun.

Thus [VxeD, G(x)] -> [VyeD, F(y)]

V is the computer science symbol for universal quantification. E below is the existential quantifier.

I'm looking for a way to write a similar statement using only existential quantifiers. My best guess would be that we simply need to find a way to find the counter-example where it doesn't happen, thus negate the above.

The problem is negating it doesn't make sense. We get:

[VxeD, G(x)] ^ [EyeD, !L(y)]

It's not a proper statement since the universal is still in there though it is also equivalent. Thus I need to re-fabricate my statement to something like: VxeD, VyeD, G(x) ^ F(y) I would get ExeD, EyeD, !G(x) v !F(y) which would mean "There exists someone who doesn't learn or someone else who doesn't have fun" which doesn't seem correct to me.

Some guidance or clarification would be fantastic :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Last minute of inspiration! How about "For anyone who does not play, there are others who do not have fun" or symbolically:

[ExeD, !G(x)] -> [EyeD, !F(y)]

Would that work? Heh.

Comment: Funny, but nobody has mentioned that your formal statement of logic is not equivalent to your original statement. D should stand for "people present" or "people able to play," or just plain "us." As it is, your equation says "If people playing the game play the game..." which seems a bit circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your `^` symbol, but I believe you are looking for the contrapositive. In your example, if the original statement is:

`[VxeD, G(x)] -> [VyeD, F(y)]`

then the contrapositive is

`[ExeD, !F(x)] -> [EyeD, !G(y)]`

meaning "if there is someone who is not having fun, then there exists someone not playing the game." Note that this is different than the statement in your comment above: it may well be the case that everyone is having fun, but not everyone is playing.

In general, `p -> q` is equivalent to `!q -> !p`.

(Of course I may not have understood your notation correctly.)

Comment: ^ means "and" and v means "or" that's basically what I got in my answer. Great, you've affirmed what I had thought! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble reading your notation. I'll use A for the universal quantifier, E for the existence quantifier, F for the predicate 'having fun', G for the predicate 'playingng learned the game', then

AxL(x) -> AxF(x)

Now, you can just apply the usual gymnastics:

<==> !AxL(x) <- !AxF(x)

<==> Ex!G(x) <- Ex!F(x)

<==> Ex!F(x) -> Ex!G(x)

so, indeed, when someone's not having fun, it means not everybody played the game.

Comment: Much cleaner than the original.